# Optical Flow in python

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

Can someone show me an example of how to use cv.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK in python? I've looked over the internet and can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This [webpage](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html) from the OpenCV-Python Documentation can help understanding the Optical Flow algorithm with source code. The source code can also be found in the OpenCV installation folder : `C:\opencv\samples\python2\lk-track.py`.

**EDIT**

[This](http://jayrambhia.com/blog/lucas-kanade-tracker/) also can help.(Explanation+SC+Demo)